# kafka consumer list API

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am new to kafka. Is there any API to list the result same as `kafka-consumer-groups.sh/bat` file does.

`kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server localhost:9091   --list`

Comment: Yes... These shell commands all run Java classes

Answer (score 0):

Best bet would be to use the `KafkaAdminClient` class (if you are using an version 0.11 or newer (cf https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-117%3A+Add+a+public+AdminClient+API+for+Kafka+admin+operations)

> `ConsumerGroupCommand` is added to `KafkaAdminClient` is AK 2.0 release: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-222+-+Add+Consumer+Group+operations+to+Admin+API

For older versions, as pointed out by @cricket_007, you can look into the script to see what class it actually uses and you can embed this class in you own code to call it directly.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply @ Matthias J. Sax and @cricket_007. After checking Admin client API I wasn't able to find any API for my requirement. then I started looking for the java classes used inside Kafka-consumer-groups.bat file and found the below command it might be running   ConsumerGroupCommand. Which is written in Scala. Is there any simple way to handle this?

Comment: the command it is running  ::                                                                           "java" -Xmx256M -server -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dkafka.logs.dir=confluent-3.2.0\confluent-3.2.0/logs  -cp .;\share\java\kafka\kafka-clients-0.10.2.0-cp1.jar";"\share\java\kafka\*"  kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand --bootstrap-server localhost:9092   --list

Comment: Just realized that `ConsumerGroupCommand` is added to KafkaAdminClient in upcoming 2.0 release. If you cannot wait for this, you can add a dependency to `<artifactId>kafka-core</artifactId>` and than use `kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand` directly in your own code by calling `ConsumerGroupCommand#main()` and passing in the corresponding command line arguments. Or, as a (better) alternative, dig into `ConsumerGroupCommand` and extract that code that issues the actual request. Internally, `ConsumerGroupCommand` uses the old `kafka.admin.AdminClient` that issues the actual request to the broker.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax  Correct me if I'm wrong.  AdminClient newer consumer group methods  only provides  committed offset per consumer group. Do you know if there is a way to get the lag and log end offset for each topic in AdminClient ? If not how would I get something like in java ?

Comment: What do you mean by "each topic" -- committed offsets are tied to consumer groups and topics. Thus, there is not notion of global "lag", but "lag" is only defined for a consumer group. You can get a list of all topic though, and also use a `KafkaConsumer` to get the `endOffset()` for all partitions of all those topics.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.
This is the below code to  get the values of consumer list

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
String[] arg = new String[3];
arg[0] = "--bootstrap-server";
arg[1] = " localhost:9092";
arg[2] = "--list";

String[] resultArray = new String[3];
ConsumerGroupCommand.ConsumerGroupCommandOptions checkArgs = new ConsumerGroupCommand.ConsumerGroupCommandOptions(
    arg);
checkArgs.checkArgs();
List<String> result = new ConsumerGroupCommand.KafkaConsumerGroupService(checkArgs).listGroups();
System.out.println(result);
result.copyToArray(resultArray);
java.util.List<String> names = java.util.Arrays.asList(resultArray);

System.out.println("result" + names);

//the below line will print the value in console 
ConsumerGroupCommand.main(arg);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<String> listConsumersGroups() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    AdminClient admin = AdminClient.create(config);
    ListConsumerGroupsResult result = admin.listConsumerGroups();
    Collection<ConsumerGroupListing> listings = result.valid().get();
    List<String> consumerGroups = new ArrayList<>(listings.size());
    listings.forEach(l->consumerGroups.add(l.groupId()));
    return consumerGroups; 
}
```